# conveniently query the value of any client-side configuration option

Tags: ssh, openssh

If I want to see whether option X is enabled for host Y, I can:

1. scan /etc/ssh/ssh_config for a section matching that host
2. Look for a setting for that option
3. Do the same for ~/.ssh/config
4. Look in the documentation for the default value of that option.

However that's kind of a lot of steps and the client program itself does all of these things when it starts up, so it seems like there must be a way to just get the client to provide the answer.  Is there?